# VB.NET: Inserting data to DataGridView that is connected to MS Access Database

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, visual-studio-2019

I'm creating a system where user selects books that he needs. As I have developed my system, creating an Admin Module is as important to the system.

Here I have my own problem where I want to insert data from a DataGridView that is already connected to the database which is MS Access. It doesn't give me errors but when I run it and tested it, it appears that something is not write of processing on the program. The error was

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.'

What I actually want is that the DataGridView can be updated at the same time with the MS Access that is connected to.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Register
    Dim provider As String
    Dim datafile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.Text.Equals("TVL12") Then
            TVL12.Show()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub addBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addBtn.Click
        Admin.table.Rows.Add(booknameReg.Text, authorReg.Text, publisherReg.Text, subjectcodeReg.Text, priceReg.Text, discountamountReg.Text)
        'TVL12.BookListTVL.Rows.Add(booknameReg.Text, authorReg.Text, publisherReg.Text, subjectcodeReg.Text, priceReg.Text, discountamountReg.Text)'
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        datafile = "C:\Users\acjfc\OneDrive\Desktop\thesis\DATABASE\BookLists.accdb"
        connString = provider & datafile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "Insert into TVL12([Book Name],[Author],[Publisher],[Subject Code],[Price],[DiscountAmount]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Book Name", CType(booknameReg.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Author", CType(authorReg.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Publisher", CType(publisherReg.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Subject Code", CType(subjectcodeReg.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Price", CType(priceReg.Text, String)))
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("DiscountAmount", CType(discountamountReg.Text, String)))
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            booknameReg.Clear()
            authorReg.Clear()
            publisherReg.Clear()
            subjectcodeReg.Clear()
            priceReg.Clear()
            discountamountReg.Clear()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Admin.MainData.DataSource = Admin.table
    End Sub
End Class
```

As you can see, the code "TVL12.BookListTVL.Rows.Add(booknameReg.Text, authorReg.Text, publisherReg.Text, subjectcodeReg.Text, priceReg.Text, discountamountReg.Text)" has been turned into comment for it wouldn't work if I remove the '' thing. Although I've done it with the other one which is not really connected to database. Can someone help me what the problem is here?

Comment: The shown error appears fairly clear. You cannot programmatically “add” rows directly to the `DataGridView` when the grid is data-bound (has a data source). As your code demonstrates, you “can” programmatically add rows to the “data source” which in turn will update the grids rows. I am not sure what is mysterious here?

Comment: Your grid is not connected to your database. That's not how ADO.NET works. Your grid is bound to your `DataTable`, which is a disconnected copy of the data in the database. The user can add data directly through the grid but, if you want to add data in code, you need to work with the `DataTable` or you can work with a `BindingSource` that sits between the two. What you should be doing is calling `Fill` on a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` from the database, making changes to that `DataTable`, then calling `Update` on the same data adapter to save those changes back to the database.

Comment: Yeah and I'm really thinking about that. I just thought that my DataGridView is connected to the database but it wasn't. Now how do I basically connect my DataGridView to the Database? What I'm actually doing now is that I'm using BindingSource to add new rows to the datagridview at the same time in the database, like it would just update simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to update the datagridview when you add data to database.

You can refer to the modified code I wrote.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newtable = New DataTable()
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    datafile = "C:\Users\testuser\Documents\BookLists.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    'str = "Insert into TVL12([Name],[Age],[StuId]) Values (?,?,?)"
    'Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    'cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Name", CType("test4", String)))
    'cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Age", CType(26, Int32)))
    'cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("StuId", CType(1004, Int32)))

    Try
        'cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        str = "Select * from TVL12"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(newtable)
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    DataGridView1.DataSource = newtable
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok so. As I've think that, is it possible that if you have input a data from your database it can update the datagridview just by using that code of yours to an UpdateButton so that once that I clicked the UpdateButton the DataGridView will just update immediately?

Comment: Where did that variable "newtable" came from?

Comment: If you want to update the datagridview when you input a data from the database, you can delete the comment code. The newtable came from the first line code, the purpose of creating newtable is to set datasource.

Comment: so the variable "newtable" is the one I'll be using so I can input data from datagridview? But once that I tried doing your code... The OleDbDataAdapter which is "da" makes my code didn't insert data from my DataBase.

Comment: I think that your variable "newtable" is just a DataTable without anything in it. and that da.Fill(newtable), is that where the database fills a Table to the DataTable?

Comment: The "newtable" is just a datatable. According to the latest two comment, I am confused. Because my original code has updated the datagridview and database at the same time. Now I am not sure what the problem you are meeting.

Comment: The main problem is that how do you insert data to DataGridView that displays the datas of the database(Connected that is but not officially).

Comment: I've tried your code, I think this was the shorter version of the one I tried. However Idk what is happening like my MS Access didn't get updated unlike my first code. Neither the DataGridView from TVL12 Form. It only did update the Admin DataGridView which is not actually connected to database.

Comment: Ok sorry that I didn't understand you and your code, as I checked on it. The unicode character string "Select * from Table" was to update the DataGridView, however... As I reset the program it goes back to normal like the data that I inserted wasn't there, although in my database(MS Access) the data was there, idk why. I tried doing TVL12.TVL12TableAdapter1.Update(BookListsDataSet1) so it would save the next time I run it again.

Comment: As usual, we don't need to reset the program.  If we update the datagirdview, the data will not change automatically. Therefore, I suggest that it is best for you to delete the reset function.

Comment: What do you mean delete the reset function? Where can I do that?

Comment: What I mean reseting the program is that clicking the stop button on the top where you should be starting up the program

Comment: After I update the datagridview, I tried stopping the program and restart it again to see if it updates. As I tried to do that, the datagridview didn't actually update as like saving it. Although my database seems to be updatedly fine

Comment: Okay, it seems that we have complicated this issue. Now, I will explain again. For your original question, you want to update the datagridview when you insert the data  to database. First, you can insert data directly according to the textbox text. Then, after inserting the data of database, you can get the result from the database. Finally, you can re-update the datagridview accroding to the result.

Comment: I know right xD, as if I can startup a new topic here in this discussion.

Comment: So just by clicking the Data Source right on the left side and just add new database and connect it to the DataGridView?? In myself it just doesn't make sense. I mean I coded this to insert database and update DataGridView. But why would I add new database just for to update the DataGridView? Is there any other option for updating the DataGridView's Data not in just Manual?

Answer (score 0):

You have an add button that inserts a new record in the database table. Try to keep your subs and functions doing only one thing. You can call `DisplayData` after the insert and also in the Form.Load.

I question the datatypes of some of the fields in your table. If Subject Code is a number it should be an Integer. Price and Discount Amount should be Decimal.

I had to guess what type your parameters are. Check your database for the real types. The last parameter of the .Add method is the size of the field. It is not necessary to call `.ToString` on a `.Text` property. It is already a string.

Using...End Using blocks close and dispose you database objects even it there is an error.

```vb
Private Sub addBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles addBtn.Click
    Try
        Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\acjfc\OneDrive\Desktop\thesis\DATABASE\BookLists.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into TVL12 ([Book Name],[Author],[Publisher],[Subject Code],[Price],[DiscountAmount]) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)", myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("BookName", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = booknameReg.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Author", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = authorReg.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Publisher", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = publisherReg.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("SubjectCode", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = subjectcodeReg.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("Price", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = priceReg.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("DiscountAmount", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = discountamountReg.Text
            myConnection.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    ClearTextBoxes()
    DisplayData()
End Sub

Private Sub ClearTextBoxes()
    booknameReg.Clear()
    authorReg.Clear()
    publisherReg.Clear()
    subjectcodeReg.Clear()
    priceReg.Clear()
    discountamountReg.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayData()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using myConnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\acjfc\OneDrive\Desktop\thesis\DATABASE\BookLists.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From TVL12", myConnection)
        myConnection.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```